# Tokudb hot backup in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, database-backups, tokudb

how Tokudb hot backup can be used in MariaDB comminuty edition?
(https://github.com/percona/tokudb-backup-plugin)

I have read that now this library is included in community edition, but 
this SQL gives out error:

```
set tokudb_backup_exclude='/lost\\+found($|/)';
set tokudb_backup_throttle=10000000;
set tokudb_backup_dir='/backups/mariadb/';
```

unknown variables.

10.1.9-MariaDB-log: tokudb-7.5.7